# Applescript - How to tell application to open a specific menu item

Tags: applescript, automator

This is my first attempt to create an applescript.

What i'd like to do is create an apple script and then assing a custom shortcut to it so that it is launched when i need it.

I need it to quickly expand Thunderbird's `insert -> HTML...` menu.

My current applescript is nested into an automator workflow, and the code is the following:

```
on run {input, parameters}
   tell application "Thunderbird"
        activate
            tell application "System Events"
                tell process "Thunderbird"
                     click menu item 6 of menu 1 of menu bar item "Insert" of menu bar 1
                end tell
            end tell
    end tell
 return input
end run
```

And when i launch it (after grant permissions to automator), this is the error i get:

> Syntax error: System Events got an error; Can't get menu bar item
>   "Insert" of menu bar 1 of process "Thunderbird"

I think that the proble is because the "Insert" menu is only available when the "Write new message" panel is open in thunderbird...

So my question is, how can i change the script above so that instead of only checking for "Thunderbird" app, it checks that both "thunderbird" and it's own "write new message" panel are open?

And also, is it liklely to be for this reason that i get this error, or i made some mistake in my applescript creation?

Thanks a lot and feel free to ask for more details.

Comment: Is there anything in the Thunderbird dictionary pointing you in the direction of opened "new message" window/document/etc.?

Comment: yes, in the main app top menu: File -> New -> Message (or cmd + N)
but everytime i'll call my shortcut to lunch this script i will be already in the "Write new message" panel as i would have probably pressed "Reply" first...

Comment: Sorry I don't have Thunderbird, so I can't give you final solution, but the goal is to check on front window of Thunderbird, the UI element which must be present to be in "Write new message" status.  to check if there or not, use get in a 'try/end' try block.